# Firebase short links fallback link

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using Firebase dynamic links with link [shortener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener) and I want to define fallback link for clients beside Android and iOS. [Manually constructed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually) dynamic links have parameter `ofl` that does exactly what I need `The link to open on platforms beside Android and iOS`. However it seems that this parameter is missing in shortener documentation. Although `ofl` is mention in the description of link parameter in shortener docs `When users open a Dynamic Link on a desktop web browser, they will load this URL (unless the ofl parameter is specified)`.

Is it possible to somehow add a fallback url for clients beside Android and iOS (e.g. web) to redirect users there instead of `link` parameter

Answer (score 10):

By using REST API

```
POST https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=api_key
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "dynamicLinkInfo": {
    "domainUriPrefix": "https://example.page.link",
    "link": "https://www.example.com/",
    "androidInfo": {
      "androidPackageName": "com.example.android"
    },
    "iosInfo": {
      "iosBundleId": "com.example.ios"
    },
    "desktopInfo": {
      "desktopFallbackLink": "https://www.other-example.com/"
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: @RyanRomanchuk

By reading the python-firebase lib source code

Comment: Thanks, i swear they used to have ofl in the console as well, bet it looks like it has been removed. Can confirm key/value for desktopInfo is working as expected for this REST call though

Comment: OMG you just saved my life, thank you so much. One extra thing I had to do is whitelist the URL I want to use as fallback in Firebase Console, after that everything finally worked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Works for me. It is really strange that Google hasn't included 'desktopInfo' param in their official documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to set fallback url in short dynamic link is to create long link manually and then use sdk to convert it to short one:

```
val longLink = "$domain/?link=$deepLink&apn=$androidPackage&ibi=$iosPackage&isi=$iosAppStoreId&ofl=$desktopFallbackLink"

FirebaseDynamicLinks
                .getInstance()
                .createDynamicLink()
                .setLongLink(Uri.parse(link))
                .buildShortDynamicLink()
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    val shortLink = it.shortLink
                    //do something with the link here
                }
```